# Delphi : Operator not aplicable to this operand type

Tags: delphi, integer, operators, operand

im a beginner to Aplication forms in Delphi, i need a little help please.  So its basically a program that does Aritmetic count for numbers from 
Memo box. I wanna also add interval to it. (-15;20>  And i wanna do it for all ODD numbers.

Variables are listed here
soucet:SUM,
pocet:count of numbers, 
Prumer:Arithmetic mean

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var soucet,prumer,x:  Real;
i,pocet:Integer;
begin
Memo1.Clear;
soucet:=0;
pocet:=0;
i:=0;
While i<= Memo1.Lines.Count-1 do begin     --
x:=StrToFloat (Memo1.lines[i]);          --
If (x>-5) and (x<=5) then begin
   soucet:= soucet + x;
   inc(pocet);
end;
 inc(i);
end;
If pocet>0 then begin
  prumer:=soucet/pocet;
  Memo1.Text:= floattostr(prumer);
 end
 else Memo1.Text:= 'Žádná čísla z intervalu (-15;20>';
```

But i only want this code to be for ODD numbers...

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var soucet,prumer,x:  Real;
i,pocet:Integer;
begin
Memo1.clear;
soucet:=0;
pocet:=0;
i:=0;
While i<= Memo1.Lines.Count-1 do begin     --
x:=StrToFloat (Memo1.lines[i]);          --
If (x>-5) and (x<=5) then begin
  If x mod 2<>0 then begin
    soucet:= soucet + x;
    inc(pocet);
  end;
end;
  inc(i);

end;
If pocet>0 then begin
  prumer:=soucet/pocet;
  Memo1.Text:= floattostr(prumer);
 end
 else Memo1.Text:= 'Žádná čísla z intervalu (-15;20>';
```

The problem is that it shows : Operator not aplicable to this operand type.
What should i do to remove this error ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Solomone! On which line is the error shown?

Comment: You know that you can do this without iteration?

Comment: "It just doesnt work" is not a valid problem description. You must be precise and clear about what happens.

Comment: I reverted your edit. A new question is, a new question. You asked about a specific compiler error, and your question was well answered. You should accept that answer.  You can't keep adding extra questions until we've written and debugged your entire program for you. Please read the area of the site carefully and try to follow the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `x`declared as `real` but the `mod`operator works on `integer`

Either

- Declare `x` as `integer` and use `StrToInt`, `TryStrToInt` or `StrToIntDef` io `StrToFloat`
- Truncate the `real` to an `int` like this: `if Trunc(x) mod 2 <> 0` or even better use the built-in `odd` function like this: `if odd(Trunc(x))`

This will solve your immediate problem but you might want to read up on

- input validation
- clean code

and not related to your current code but important enough to mention

- error/resource handling *(try...finally)*

Comment: Tank you very much. I apreciate your answer

Comment: @Solomone - No problem. If this solves your question, you can mark it as such by using the checkmark next to it.

Comment: Better to use the `odd` function. Also, in general, the best error handling involves **not** writing `try/except`.

Comment: Oh, i just got another problem and i cant solve it.. :( Its just.. Weird.. No error shown, everything look so right, but it isnt.. :D (Ive added more information to topic)

Comment: Solomone, use the debugger to step into the code to see what happens.

Comment: @Solomone If this has solved the original question (ie: operator not applicable...) the correct thing to do is to mark it as accepted (put the green checkmark) and if you now have a new question, then ask that as a separate new question.

Comment: :D Thanks for your replies guys.. It was just .. stupid mistake.. The Memo1.Clear cant be there.. It is in form1.Create :D